# C#, StringToEnum, can I make it a generic function out of this

Tags: c#

I'd like to have a simple helper method for converting a string to an Enum. Something like the following, but it doesn't like T as the first argument in the Enum.Parse. The error is T is a Type Parameter but is used like a variable.

```
public static T StringToEnum<T>(String value)
        {
            return (T) Enum.Parse(T,value,true) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static T StringToEnum<T>(String value)
{
     return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```

Comment: This should do the job. To expand on it: specifying T is just like specifying int or string - you still need the typeof statement to return the actual System.Type object.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static T StringToEnum<T>(String value)
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T),value,true) ;
}
```

What you were doing is like using 'int' as a Type, but it is not a Type object.  To get the Type object, you would use typeof(int).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method extension I use.

```
/// <summary>
/// Will parse and string value and return the Enum given.  Case is ignored when doing the parse.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="typeOfEnum">The type of the Enum to Parse</param>
/// <param name="value">The string value for the result of the Enum</param>
/// <param name="errorValue">If an error is encountered this value is returned.  (For example could be an Enum)</param>
/// <returns>Returns Enum Object</returns>
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```